# Problem with mathjax rendering in profiles

Tags: bug, mathjax

There is a weird Mathjax alignment in question titles of user profiles.
I am using chrome on apple.

Here are two screen shots examples from different user profiles.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I think it would help for you to articulate what is "weird" in these displays.  Having links to these user profiles would help my tired old eyes from straining to pick out the user indexes from the images.

Comment: @hardmath What is weird is illustrated by the screenshots. It is not user specific, and the profiles where I took these pictures ca be inferred by the user number (on top of the screenshots): [369188](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/369188/hamam-abdallah) and [58320](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/58320/macavity).